# how to iterate each row using CTE in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

[for each dept, multiple employee and each employee's date columns all are zero. how to get this rows through postgres query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3fjy.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfHNk.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3fjy.png)

Comment: If you want some help, you need to post table create, sample datas, the expected result and bring more detail on your problem. What have you tried ? Do you have error message...

Comment: Everything Philippe mentioned should be included in the question as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Screen shots are [not really helpful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)